# how to enter an array with specific values in to specific location in memory in assembly?

Tags: assembly

the values are :

```
Data segment
array db 7, 0F4h, 86h, 0A5h, 200, 6, 0F2h, -2, -17, 0FFh
Data ends
```

and i need to store them **using a loop** to adress 100h to 110h .

and then turn all positive numbers to negative , also using a loop .

if someone knows i appricate the help !

Comment: Which instruction set?

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. Exactly what part of the exercise are you having trouble with? And has been asked, what assembly language are you talking about?

Comment: show us your approach. SO isn't a coding service

Comment: Like in any other language, you use the available commands ("instructions" in assembly) and expressions (basically "none" in assembly, use only instructions, any "expression" in code must be compile-time type of expression, which is compiled as valid instruction of CPU) to achieve what you want. From the question it looks almost like you are not even aware of what CPU you are targetting, and what instructions are available, then the most obvious answer is to "hire a programmer". If you want to learn it yourself, start learning.

Comment: Do you have to produce `-abs(x)`, or could you just OR with `0x80` to make all numbers negative, but not the 2's complement negation of the original?  (Oh wait, that would make 0 negative, but 0 isn't positive.)

Comment: Your array only has 10 elements, not 10h.  What are you supposed to fill the last 6 elements with?  Assuming you're on x86, I'd use `pabsb xmm1, [array]` / `pxor xmm0,xmm0` / `psubb xmm1, xmm0` / `movdqa [100h], xmm1` to produce `-abs(x)` for 16 inputs at once.  Loops are boring.